# 2002 Ford Escape sputters at and accelerates slowly from stops

Tags: fuel-injection, fuel-pump

I ran two cans of sea foam through it. I replaced the fuel filter, I cleaned the MAF and idle air control, and I put a new air filter in it. All that made it a little better but the problem is still there. At stops power surges periodically.

Is it the fuel pump?

Comment: Have you checked the fuel pressure?

Comment: nope. I didn't even know that was a thing. I'll try at the next opportunity.

Comment: Any check engine codes being thrown?

Comment: the only check engine light is from the idle air control which has a small leak. but that doesn't show up until after you drive the car for a few hours and the problem I'm describing happens before the light goes on so I don't know if it will be caught by the check engine light but yeah I can check that too that's a good point I forgot about that